# Merge array into array of objects

Tags: javascript, api

I'm working with API data and I'm trying to build an object combining multiple arrays of data.

Current Arrays:

```
let name = [{name: "John"},{name: "Jane"},{name: "Doe",}]
let arr1 = ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar']
let arrX = ...
```

Desired Outcome:

```
let desiredOutcome = [
{
    name: "John",
    arr1: "bar", ...

},
{
    name: "Jane",
    arr1: "foo", ...
},
{
    name: "Doe",
    arr1: "foobar", ...
}]
```

I've been trying to play around with Object.assign() but I haven't had any luck:

```
var merge = Object.assign(obj, arr1 )
```

Is there a method or methods I could use?

Comment: There is no way to access the variable names, you'd have to hardcode them or have them be properties of an object.

Comment: using a loop, for every name object in the name object array, add the respective 'arr1' index value to the name object?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` to add each element.

```js
let name = [{name: "John"},{name: "Jane"},{name: "Doe",}]
let arr1 = ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar']

let result = name.map((a,i)=>{a.arr1 = arr1[i]; return a})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Where does the literal key "arr1" in the object come from? Can you explode the code please?

Comment: if you mean `a.arr1`, it is used to create a property and assign the value immediately if not existed. is the same as `a["arr1"]` or `a = {"arr1": null}`

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Strange it’s allowed with dot notation there

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `Array.map`

Try the following:

```js
let name = [{name: "John"},{name: "Jane"},{name: "Doe",}]
let arr1 = ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar'];

var result = name.map((o,i) =>Object.assign({"arr1" : arr1[i]},o));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary count of arrays, you could take an array with the array of objects and the arrays of values and take [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) which preserves the name of the array and the values for adding to the result set with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var names = [{ name: "John" }, { name: "Jane" }, { name: "Doe" }],
    arr1 = ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar'],
    arrX = [1, 2, 3],
    result = [names, { arr1 }, { arrX }]
        .reduce((r, o) =>
            (([k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => Object.assign({}, r[i], { [k]: v })))(Object.entries(o)[0])
        );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late but I'll provide some additional explanation on how to use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

The method takes in one callback as argument. The callback itself can take predefined arguments. Here we will use the first two:

- currentValue: `e`
- index: `i`

Basically, the map method works by associating (literally mapping) each element of the looped array (here **`name`**) to the given returned value (here **`{name: e.name, arr1: arr1[i]}`**). Mapping is just a bijection between two arrays.

---

Another word on `(e,i) => ({name: e.name, arr1: arr1[i]})`:

It is the shorthand syntax called arrow function. It is similar to defining the callback function like so:

```
function(e,i) {

  return { name: e.name, arr1: arr1[i] };

}
```

---

Full snippet will look like:

```js
const name = [{name: "John"},{name: "Jane"},{name: "Doe",}]
const arr1 = ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar']

const result = name.map((e,i) => ({ name: e.name, arr1: arr1[i] }))

console.log(result)
```